# XLSX Download is Corrupt Apache POI to ByteArrayOutputStream w/ ResponseEntity<Resource>

Tags: java, excel, angular, spring, apache-poi

I have an Angular app that downloads a file via a Spring web service API call. The method for this in the Controller looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/exportExcel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> exportExcel(Principal user) throws Exception {

    try {
        //FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("MeasuresExport.xls");
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); // creates the workbook
        wb.createSheet("sheet1");
        //FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\MeasuresExport.xlsx");
        wb.write(stream);
        wb.close();

        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "force-download"));
        header.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=MeasuresExport.xlsx");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ByteArrayResource(stream.toByteArray()),
                header, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Failed creating and sending excel export");
    }
}
```

However, while it downloads just fine and seems to have a 2.7KB filesize (about what I'd expect for an XLS file with only a sheet created, a common issue seems to be not having a sheet at all) - the file attempts to open but warns it is corrupt and never can repair it.

I've tried a few other things - such as using FileOutputStream instead and/or adding rows/cells and the like, but it seems the best practice is to use ByteArrayOutputStream and not FileOutputStream, and essentially return a ResponseEntity and return the toByteArray() representation of the stream. I removed some of the extra rows/cells being added from this code, just to eliminate possible issues. For reference, though you probably won't need it, the Angular code to call this looks something like:

```
exportMeasures(aMeasures: Measure[]): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(
  environment.apiUrl + '/measure/exportExcel',
  { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' }
  );
}
```

And above all, that seems to work just fine and downloads the file, just that it appears to be a *corrupt* file. Eventually, that aMeasures bit will be important, but for right now all I'm really trying to do is get it to return a valid XLSX file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue? Well, it wasn't anything code-related. My changes were not hot-deploying as I was expecting them to, and so a clean/repackage/restart seemed to work!